# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in R

Tags: r, pca

I was wondering if its possible to have multiple categorical values in PCA. For example, when looking at the well known Iris dataset there is just one categorical variable(species) but what if we to add in another (color)?  Im sure there must be a way but i'm not entirely sure and looking for suggestions! Thx!

```
pca_graph <- ggbiplot(pca_flowers, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
          groups = species, ellipse = TRUE, 
          circle = TRUE)
pca_graph <- pca_graph + scale_color_discrete(name = '')
pca_graph <- pca_graph + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
           legend.position = 'top')
print(pca_graph)
```

Comment: You could have as many columns of categorical variables as you like and use them in PCA visualization _e.g._ to color points in a chart by factor. But only numeric values are used in the PCA calculation itself _e.g._ columns 1-4 in the iris example.

Comment: @neilfws based on the code i entered above how to could i modify that to work for multiple categorical variables? Right now it only accounts for species. What if i wanted to account for species and color?

Comment: It looks as though the `groups` parameter for that function takes only one factor variable. I guess you could create a new one by pasting together the values for species and colour in a new column, let's say `species_color`, then `groups = species_color`. But personally I would not visualize > 1 factor in one biplot, it gets confusing. I'd consider separate plots or facets.

Comment: You could use shape for the second factor though I agree, potentially hard to read.